Question about String Reversal in C Code: Why does the string appear reversed at the end?
I have this C code where I am trying to reverse a string using inline assembly. However, I am curious to know how the reversed string is displayed at the end:
printf("Reversed string: %s\n", str);
and if there is any relation to the lack of outputs declared in the constraints.
I am particularly interested in understanding how the reversed string stored in the str array is passed to the printf function for display.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[10000]; // Allow for 10000 characters

    // Prompt user for input
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    // Remove newline character if present
    char *nl = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (nl != NULL) {
        *nl = '\0';
    } else {
        printf("Line too long or no newline character found.\n");
    }

    // Validate string length
    int length = strlen(str);
    if (length > 50) {
        printf("String exceeds 50 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Inline assembly to reverse the string
    __asm__ (
        "mov %[len], %%esi\n\t"    // esi = length
        "decl %%esi\n\t"            // esi = length - 1 (last character index)
        "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"      // ecx = 0 (starting index)
        "reverse_loop:\n\t"
        "cmp %%esi, %%ecx\n\t"      // Compare start and end indexes
        "jge loop_end\n\t"          // If start >= end, end loop
        "movb (%[str], %%ecx), %%al\n\t"    // al = str[ecx]
        "movb (%[str], %%esi), %%bl\n\t"    // bl = str[esi]
        "movb %%bl, (%[str], %%ecx)\n\t"    // str[ecx] = bl
        "movb %%al, (%[str], %%esi)\n\t"    // str[esi] = al
        "incl %%ecx\n\t"            // Increment start index
        "decl %%esi\n\t"            // Decrement end index
        "jmp reverse_loop\n\t"      // Repeat loop
        "loop_end:\n\t"
        :
        : [str] "r" (str), [len] "r" (length)
        : "%esi", "%ecx", "%al", "%bl"
    );

    // Print the reversed string
    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}

Constraints:
:
: [str] "r" (str), [len] "r" (length)
: "%esi", "%ecx", "%al", "%bl"

Could someone please shed some light on this behavior and provide insights into how the absence of declared outputs in the constraints might affect it?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

esi is counting down from the end, ecx is counting up from the start. The code swaps the indexed letters until they meet in the middle.

What part of the code is unclear? Everything?

There are no outputs because the string is reversed in place.

The asm statement is missing a "memory" clobber.  It probably can't break in this function because you're just passing a pointer to an opaque function (printf) after the asm statement, but see How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?

Also, it's inefficient to ask the compiler for a value in a register and then start the asm block with a mov to another register.  See Can I modify input operands in gcc inline assembly for how to tell the compiler about an input you can modify so you could e.g.  dec %[len] / jne reverse_loop
